# Creating a c# application/windows service that runs once a day

Tags: windows, service, alwayson

Hi I need to create an application that runs once a day. The app can run at any time of the day right after the user login for the first time within the day.

My question, what is the best approach to do this. Should I create a windows service or windows application to do this?

Another requirement is that the app must run once a day no matter what unless it has been uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: Could you elaborate your solution please? How to use the Windows Task Scheduler to satisfy the requriements?

Comment: Whatever application you are writing, focus on what is meant to do and let Windows Task Scheduler take care of scheduling when the application will be invoked. A service is not necessarily useful, unless the application is polling periodically for some sort of an event or performing some action throughout the day. You could write a C# application either as a console application or a Windows Forms application. Ultimately, you will end up with an executable (.exe) file. In Scheduler, you can specify the path of the executable, along with date/time/frequency and application arguments.